# Deleting all variant images in Shopify using CSV importer

Tags: csv, shopify

I need to delete all product variant images from a Shopify store which has 1700 products. Doing this manually isn't an option so I have exported the products into an CSV file and have deleted all the image urls under 'Variant Image'. However, when I import back in I get 154 errors as below:

```
Line 2150-2171: Validation failed: Variants is invalid and Options are not unique
Line 2173-2211: Validation failed: Options are not unique
```

What am I doing wrong? I still need to be able to keep the variant options (so 'size' and 'colour') but delete their associated image.

Thanks in advance!

---

The errors are as above and my CSV data is structured into the below columns:

```
Handle
Title
Body (HTML)
Vendor
Type
Tags
Published
Option1 Name
Option1 Value
Option2 Name
Option2 Value
Option3 Name    
Option3 Value   
Variant SKU Variant Grams   
Variant Inventory Tracker   
Variant Inventory Qty   
Variant Inventory Policy    
Variant Fulfillment Service 
Variant Price   
Variant Compare At Price    
Variant Requires Shipping   
Variant Taxable
Variant Barcode Image Src   
Image Alt Text  
Gift Card   
SEO Title   
SEO Description 
Variant Image
```

When I import this into Shopify with all the variant images in the 'Variant Image' column it works with no errors but when I simply delete the data in this column it throws 154 errors like:

```
Line 2278-2287: Validation failed: Variants is invalid and Options are not unique
Line 2322-2331: Validation failed: Options are not unique
```

Comment: Can you show some of the csv lines you are trying to import? shopify only offers this explaination http://docs.shopify.com/manual/your-store/products/common-import-issues#line